# Where can I find a device class id

Tags: c#

I am trying to detect a specific usb smart card reader using something like:

```
public IntPtr HwndHandler(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr LParam, ref bool handled)
```

Where can I know the class id?

```
private const string USBClassID = "A5DCBF10-6530-11D2-901F-00C04FB951ED";
```

Is all the class id same for all the device?

Comment: What you are trying for?? please explain in detail

Comment: I am trying to detect when the usb smart card reader is plug in to the pc.